# Do we need to propagate state covariance matrix 'P' during missing observations in the Extended Kalman Filter?

Tags: estimation, kalman-filter, state-space-models, filter

Basically as the title says: in a scenario, we have missing observations where the entire state vector is unknown for consecutive time steps. Do we just run through the prediction section of the algorithm and not the update section for both the state vector X and the covariance matrix P?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether a state estimate is required at the current time step. If no state estimations are needed until new measurements become available, it would likely be more efficient to delay the state propagation until new measurements are present. In this case, you can propagate the state over the entire time interval (dt) that lies between the measurements and the resulting state estimate should be the same as if you were to propagate the state multiple times through smaller time intervals. Please let me know if I understood your question correctly.